# Can I get Sentry to report segfaults, and other rare fatal errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, gtk3, sentry

Once in a rare while my GTK3 Python application crashes with segfault, or some obscure error like

Gdk-WARNING **: file.py: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

Is there a way to get more info on errors like this in Sentry's Python reporter?

Comment: I dont think you can. if you're using raven-python, it relies on python vm, which can't recovery from SIGSEGV. I have no knowledge about GTK3 Python errors, but I think they were raised from a c module, at python level, raven could capture them, but lack c level details.

Comment: @georgexsh Yeah that's what I had guessed